# uniqueness of extension of a finite measure on an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I got stuck on one exercise question as follows and hope to get some help.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra on a set $X$ and $\mu$ be a countably additive measure on $\mathcal{A}$. We can prove $\mu^*: \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty]$, defined as $\mu^*(A) = \inf\{\sum_k\mu(A_k): A_ks \in \mathcal{A}, A \subseteq \cup_k A_k\}$, when restricted to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, is a measure that agrees with $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$. I am stuck at the step to show this is the only way to extend $\mu$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Currently, I have been able to show $\mu(A) \leq \mu^*(A)$ for all $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, but how to complete the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take coverings of your set by measurable sets. As your set is in $\mathcal{A}$, every set in the covering can be "split" in its intersection with $A$, and the other part. The sum of $\Sigma\mu^*(I)$ for each $I$ in the covering will trivially be larger than $\mu^*(A)$, as it is monotone, and by making finer coverings, you can "control the excess" (aka, the sums of the measures of the parts of the covering that are outside $A$) by an $\epsilon>0$. Then, you can prove with this that $\mu(A)+\epsilon\geq\mu^*(A)$ for all values of  $\epsilon$. From there, it follows what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Sorry if the detail is not enough, I'm posting from my phone, feel free to ask any doubts.